# Are Widget Fields Cached?

Tags: magento-enterprise, adminhtml, widgets

When updating the configuration for the fields of a widget, old fields are still being shown even though have they been removed. Cache has been completely flushed but they still appear. Are widget fields cached somewhere?

At first I thought that maybe the widget was pulling the values from the instance of the widget that had already been placed within the CMS page. However, I've also attempted to insert the widget into blank CMS page and the outcome is the same.

I've searched through my config to find the label text of the fields that are still showing up even though they've been deleted and I come up with zero results.

Comment: Are you able to try this out on a different server using the same code? What kind of caching are you using at a server level? APC, memcache, Reddis, Varnish, etc.

Comment: I don't believe we use any caching on our server other than the Magento caching (will hear back from the server admin shortly).

Comment: I've verified there is no server level caching enabled.

Comment: What version of Enterprise are you on? Are the CMS pages under version control?

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help me troubleshoot. I've posted the answer within my origin question since I don't have enough rep to answer my own question for another 7 hours.

Comment: You have enough rep now. Please post your answer or delete the question as it is quite too localized.

Comment: Answer now posted as an answer instead of being in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had used the module that the widget is defined in to start a new unrelated module. Unfortunately, I forgot to remove the widget.xml in the duplicated module so old revisions of the widget.xml were still being loaded. Doh!

I figured this out by grepping through my code:

```
grep --recursive "<the label text belonging to the field I deleted but was still there>" ./
```